# How to prohibit access to recent files by command line

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions

I don't want to use Windows recent folder, and I want to make the folder inaccessible for all users by command line.

I thought the command below would deny all users permissions, but even after this command the files in `Recent` folder are still created.

```
icacls C:\Users\ironsand\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent /deny Everyone:(OI)(CI)(DE,DC)
processed file: C:\Users\ironsand\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

How can I disable the folder by command line? I want this because I want to run it from a batch file.

I'm using Windows 10 Home edition.

Comment: Why not just disable it properly, from Windows’ settings? Since you don’t specify an exact Windows versions, I can’t tell you where, though. Also keep in mind that by default no user but yourself (and Administrators) can access your user profile.

Comment: Here’s a group policy that does what you want: [User Configuration → Administrative Templates → Start Menu and Taskbar → Do not keep history of recently opened documents](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940394.aspx)

Comment: Because I want to disable it by batch file, not by hand.

Comment: The simplest solution is to create a script that will modify the registry key that handles that setting.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Windows permissions are based on things like "user accounts" (or "groups"), not specific software such as a "command line interface".  Skilled command line users ought to be able to do anything that can be done via a GUI.  The most straightforward approach I instantly thought of would be to disable the command line altogether, by renaming CMD.EXE, but side effects would probably be atrocious.

I'm sure this could be done, with a custom (open source) shell.  However, I'm not anticipating an easy way to do this.  Rather than restrict how a person can access the folder, a more solid security posture would be to restrict what a person can do (regardless of how they intend to do it).

If you're trying to block something that is more specific, there might, or might not, be some more viable options; more details in what you're seeking to prevent might be helpful.

Comment: He’s not looking to keep command line users out, but to disable it programmatically, presumably to automate it on new deployments.